# How to use AWS SDK for request signing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I'm trying to invoke an api request (service: execute-api) and a Signature v4 is required. I've been going through the documentation and I see clearly this:

> Alternatively, you can use the AWS CLI or one of the AWS SDKs to
>   handle request signing for you.

I don't own the API and originally just thought I could use CURL but obviously IAM is configured. I'm wondering what the best way of making this request signed is?

Note:
Looks like there is an AWS4Signer class that may be what I'm looking for to generate the signature non-manually

Comment: Presumably you're trying to sign requests to API Gateway methods, not to AWS APIs. You can generate an SDK for your API here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html

Comment: As noted, I don't own the API so I don't have the luxury of generating the SDK. I believe what is needed is to create a signature to attach to the request, so I'm trying to work on using AWS4Signer. Will post a snippet if I get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but from your question it's not clear whether you're just experimenting with the API or if you want to write a client that calls it (as in production code).

If you're just testing, you can use Postman to call the API (it supports SigV4). Details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html).

If you are writing a client, the way to go is generating the SDK from API gateway, as noted in the comments. Should that not be possible, the next best option is to use one of the language-specific SDK signers to generate the SigV4 signature. [AWS4Signer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWS4Signer.html), like you said, is the way to go. It should be straightforward to integrate with it, but if you can share more details of your specific use case (platform, language, where do you get the AWS credentials from, etc), people can give you a better answer.

Last, if you want to generate the signature yourself, [here's how](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/signing-requests/) the canonical generation of signatures work.